# Angular multi select chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, charts, highcharts

I have one page with list menu

By using the list menu , i can create charts like : line chart or bar chart or pie chart or .... .

But i want when line chart or other chart selected and shows in page, other chart selected like line chart, pie chart or .... do not deleted existed charts in page and every selected charts form the list shows on page with different data

Actually no limit to create charts in page

1 - select chart form the chart list with data

2 - select other chart with different data

.

.

.

And more

Example of angular chart

```js
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["highcharts-ng"]);

myapp.controller('myctrl', function ($scope) {

  $scope.chartTypes = [
    {"id": "line", "title": "Line"},
    {"id": "spline", "title": "Smooth line"},
    {"id": "area", "title": "Area"},
    {"id": "areaspline", "title": "Smooth area"},
    {"id": "column", "title": "Column"},
    {"id": "bar", "title": "Bar"},
    {"id": "pie", "title": "Pie"},
    {"id": "scatter", "title": "Scatter"}
  ];


  $scope.chartSeries = [
    {"name": "Some data", "data": [1, 2, 4, 7, 3]},
    {"name": "Some data 3", "data": [3, 1, 9, 5, 2]}
  ];




  $scope.addSeries = function () {
    var rnd = [];
    $scope.chartConfig.series.push({
      data: rnd
    })
  };



  $scope.removeSeries = function (id) {
    var seriesArray = $scope.chartConfig.series;
    seriesArray.splice(id, 1)
  };




  $scope.chartConfig = {
    options: {
      chart: {
        type: 'areaspline'
      }
    },
    series: $scope.chartSeries,
    title: {
      text: 'Hello'
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: true
    }
  };




});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.src.js"></script>
<script src="http://pablojim.github.io/highcharts-ng/javascripts/highcharts-ng.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css"rel="stylesheet"/>
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="myctrl">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span9">
                <div class="row">
                    <highchart id="chart1" config="chartConfig" class="span9" ></highchart>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span4">
                <div class="row-fluid">Default Type <select ng-model="chartConfig.options.chart.type" ng-options="t.id as t.title for t in chartTypes"></select></div>
                <div class="row-fluid"><button ng-click="addSeries()">Add Series</button></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please help me friends

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highcharts-ng is rebuilding your chart when changes are made to options object in chart's config. If you will set type of series in series, then `Series.update()` should be triggered.

In Highcharts-ng:

```
scope.$watch('config.series', function (newSeries, oldSeries) {
    var needsRedraw = processSeries(newSeries);
    if (needsRedraw) {
      chart.redraw();
    }
  }, true);
```

Let's watch new variable for changes and in case it changes, let's change type of all series.

```
$scope.seriesType = 'areaspline';

$scope.chartSeries = [
  {"name": "Some data", "data": [1, 2, 4, 7, 3], "type": $scope.seriesType},
  {"name": "Some data 3", "data": [3, 1, 9, 5, 2], "type": $scope.seriesType}
];

$scope.$watch('seriesType', function (newType, oldType) {
  var series = $scope.chartConfig.series,
     len = series.length;
  for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
    series[i].type = newType;
  }
}, true);
```

While having in HTML:

```
<div class="row-fluid">Default Type <select ng-model="seriesType" ng-options="t.id as t.title for t in chartTypes"
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3mbykr8n/

Only problem here is when changing from or to `bar` series type. `bar` is forcing chart to be inverted, so you will need to rebuild the chart in that case. Changing series type to `bar` will give you `column` because series changes are not forcing chart rebuild.